# How to read files using for loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I need to read 8760 files (365 days * 24 hours = 8760) of small size (60 kb) and aggregate values and take average of some values.

Earlier, I have used the below stated code for reading *.csv files:

```
for a=1:365
for b=1:24

s1=int2str(a);
s2=int2str(b);
s3=strcat('temperature_humidity',s1,'_'s2);

data = load(s3);

% Code for aggregation, etc

end
end
```

I was able to run this code. However now the file name is little different and I am not sure how to read these files.

Files are named like this:

2005_M01_D01_0000(UTC-0800)_L00_NOX_1HR_CONC.DAT

where M = Month, so the values are 01, 01, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12; 
D = Day, so the values are 01, 02, 03, ..., 31; 
Hours is in this format: 0000, 0100, 0200, ..., 1800, ..., 2300.

Please take a look at the attached image for file name . I need to read these files. Please help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you need to extract date and time from the filenames or do you just want to read all of the matching files in arbitrary order?

Comment: Hi @Deve, I just want to read files in sequential order. If file is named like "temperature_i_j.csv" where i = 1 to 365 and j = 1 to 24, I am able to read it but now files are named like "M01_D01_0000_Conc.dat", here immediate 2 numbers on right of M varies from 01 to 12, immediate 2 numbers on right of D varies from 01 to 31 and hour changes from 0000 to 2300. I do not know how to incorporate 01, 02, 03, 0000, 01000 as file name in a for loop for reading files.

Answer (score 1):

I would use dir:

files=dir('*.dat')

Or you can construct the filenames with

name = sprintf('%d_M%2d etc.',...)